# How can I make sure Bluetooth is working every morning?

Tags: bluetooth, alarm, bluetooth-audio, volume, oneplus

I use Google Clock & Spotify as my morning alarm, with OnePlus 11 connected to my Marantz NR1200 stereo receiver.

When this works, the alarm sounds and plays. It has worked about 4 out of 5 times. But, because there is a sound delay of about 1 second between the phone speaker and the main speakers, I usually set the alarm volume on the phone very low, and to get a sufficient volume on the main speakers, I have to set the media volume on my phone at around max. The volume on my Marantz is also tied to my phone media volume, so it's set at 72.

This is kind of scary though, as sometimes if I accidentally play music from the phone or have any other media sound, this plays extremely loud on my main speakers. The alarm sound is okay, I guess because the low alarm volume and high media volume balances this out.

So, every night, I have to make sure the media volume is max, the alarm volume is low, and silent mode on the phone is activated (so as to not be shocked awake by a notification)... so, not optimal.

The real problem is when Bluetooth doesn't sound at all. It has happened about 3 times since I got the Marantz. When it happens, the alarm plays from the phone at a low volume, but nothing from the main speakers. The phone is connected via BT to the Marantz as shown in the display of the receiver, and also in the BT menu of the phone.

This makes my morning filled with some anxiety, because I am so used to waking up to music and I need this to keep working, or I might have to change receiver.

I have considered putting in the old solution from my previous receiver; a phono cable in the back of Marantz to a minijack on my phone; but having tried that the sound was awful in comparison, and because of the high volume, I could hear the speakers static constantly.

So I was hoping anyone could help me remedy this situation. I don't have enough know-how to even begin to troubleshoot this.

Any helpers?

Comment: Do you have other BT devices?

Comment: No, just the receiver and my phone